# How to fix Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 4.2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-plugin

I run a flutter app but I got this error" Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 4.2.0. " I tried updating all the plugins and android studio but I still get this error and I don't understand the other solutions in StackOverflow to the same question.